# Comparación de tablas

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con esta información:

```
  PV009_SFO:
              POS    ID     REF    ALT    AD_REF    AD_ALT   Coverage
               90    PV009  C       A       6          2         8
              177    PV009  C       A       6          2         8
              203    PV009  C       A       9          5        14
              242    PV009  C       A       6          2         8
              290    PV014  A       T       3          5         8
              355    PV009  C       A       6          2         8
              409    PV009  C       A       6          2         8  
              419    PV009  C       A       8          2        10
```

y otros similares

```
  PV014_SFO:
              POS    ID     REF    ALT    AD_REF    AD_ALT   Coverage
               84    PV014  C       A       6          2         8
              104    PV014  G       A       1          7         8
              203    PV014  C       A       6          2         8
              290    PV014  A       T       2          1         3
              350    PV014  A       A       5          2         7
              419    PV014  C       A       1          2         3


  PV061_SFO:
              POS    ID     REF    ALT    AD_REF    AD_ALT   Coverage
               90    PV061  C       A       9          2        11
              347    PV061  T       T       4          3         7
              409    PV061  C       A       0          2         2 
              419    PV061  C       A       4          4         8
```

Y  me gustaría saber en que filas tienen similitud ambos dataframes, en base a las columnas POS REF y ALT, para obtener un resultado como este:

Similarity:

```
               POS    ID               REF    ALT 
               90    PV009/PV061        C      A   
              203    PV009/PV014        C      A
              290    PV009/PV014        A      T
              409    PV009/PV061        C      A
              419    PV009/PV014/PV061  C      A
```

Finalmente estos son los datos para reproducir:

```
df1 <- structure(list(POS = c(90L, 177L, 203L, 242L, 290L, 355L, 409L, 
                       419L), ID = c("PV009", "PV009", "PV009", "PV009", "PV014", "PV009", 
                                     "PV009", "PV009"), REF = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "C", "C", 
                                                                "C"), ALT = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "T", "A", "A", "A"), AD_REF = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                  6L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 8L), AD_ALT = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                          2L, 2L), Coverage = c(8L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -8L))
df2 <- structure(list(POS = c(84L, 104L, 203L, 290L, 350L, 419L), ID = c("PV014", 
                                                                  "PV014", "PV014", "PV014", "PV014", "PV014"), REF = c("C", "G", 
                                                                                                                        "C", "A", "A", "C"), ALT = c("A", "A", "A", "T", "A", "A"), AD_REF = c(6L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               1L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L), AD_ALT = c(2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Coverage = c(8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(POS = c(90L, 347L, 409L, 419L), ID = c("PV061", 
                                                      "PV061", "PV061", "PV061"), REF = c("C", "T", "C", "C"), ALT = c("A", 
                                                                                                                       "T", "A", "A"), AD_REF = c(9L, 4L, 0L, 4L), AD_ALT = c(2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                              2L, 4L), Coverage = c(11L, 7L, 2L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `dplyr` puedes hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(df1,df2,df3) %>% 
  group_by(POS,REF,ALT) %>% 
  summarise(ID=paste(ID,collapse="/"), n=n()) %>% 
  filter(n>1)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   POS, REF [5]
    POS REF   ALT   ID                    n
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>             <int>
1    90 C     A     PV009/PV061           2
2   203 C     A     PV009/PV014           2
3   290 A     T     PV014/PV014           2
4   409 C     A     PV009/PV061           2
5   419 C     A     PV009/PV014/PV061     3
```

con `bind_rows()` unimos todos los `data.frames` en uno solo, luego simplemente agrupamos   con `group_by()` por las variables de interés y concatenamos los valores de `ID` de cada grupo, por último filtramos los que aparecen más de una vez.

Comment: Una vez más,  funciona. Gracias